# jq Filter on sub object value

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file people.json:

```
{
  "Joe" : {"Job" : "Clown", "Age" : 22},
  "Sally" : {"Job" : "Programmer", "Age" : 32},
  "Anne" : {"Job" : "Clown", "Age" : 29}
}
```

I would like to select everyone who is a Clown. My output should look like this:

```
{
  "Joe" : {"Job" : "Clown", "Age" : 22},
  "Anne" : {"Job" : "Clown", "Age" : 29}
}
```

I have tried the .. operator as in

```
cat people.json | jq '. | map(select(.Job == "Clown"))'
```

But it seems to match Joe and Anne at multiple levels and produces more output then I want. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

use `with_entries` to convert to/from an intermediate format that represents that data as an array of objects with `key` and `value` elements:

```
cat people.json | jq 'with_entries(select(.value.Job == "Clown"))'
```

as per the docs here: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using **reduce**

```
  . as $v
| reduce keys[] as $k (
    {};
    if $v[$k].Job == "Clown" then .[$k] = $v[$k] else . end
  )
```